# Text TOP Right on Image in Android

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I am trying to insert Text on the image top right. Something like this:

[image]

So I tried the following: custom_profile_image here is 50dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutforprofileimage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_profile_image"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_profile_image">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_profile_image"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepic"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/number_round"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="17sp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:minHeight="17sp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For the above XML I am getting the following output:

[image]

The problem here is that I would like to move the orange box towards the top so that it touches the tip of a profile image similar to the screenshot above. I tried lots of things, but not able to do so.

I am not sure what to do. Can you somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: change imagview padding to marginTop = "8dp" and marginRight = "8dp"

Comment: I did that top imageview has 8dp padding but the orage box came down with it.

Comment: framelayout with top padding for imageview might do

Comment: Give marginTop and marginRight property to your ImageView

Comment: Use FrameLayout with specified width and height and give little lesser width and height for image view and finally aligned the textview to the right

Comment: @sanjana first understand how margin and padding work. After that you got idea your self

Comment: Try this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159773/add-button-with-a-counter-into-the-toolbar/37160060#37160060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a marginTop to the imageview and then give the half of that as the marginTop of the textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layoutforprofileimage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/user" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tv_circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="20sp"
    android:minWidth="20sp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
```

tv_circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#F08600" />

<padding
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

For the above XML the output will be as following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Set the following attrs for `RelativeLayout`

  - `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
  - `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
- Set padding of `ImageView` to `20dp`
- Remove the following attrs for `TextView`

  - `android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"`
  - `android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"`
- Set the following attrs for `TextView`

  - `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
  - `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutforprofileimage"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="260dip"
        android:layout_height="260dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/picture_frame" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button_round_center_green"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

</FrameLayout>
```

> You can use margin and padding to adjust the position of textview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding margin to your image view
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutforprofileimage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="17sp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:minHeight="17sp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  try this
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layoutforprofileimage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bookcover"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:background="@drawable/notification_small"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:minHeight="17sp"
    android:text="100"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your layout a bit and added some of the sizes and colors you used into resource files.

The following will give you what you need. You can just modify the layout to suit your needs better.

I used the new preview view in Android Studio 2.2 to see that the layout looks good. I would suggest you use the new constraint layouts to help you out with more changes to your app and then look at the xml for best practices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutforprofileimage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/profileImageLayoutSize"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/profileImageLayoutSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_profile_image"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_profile_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profileImageSpacingForLabel"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/profileImageSpacingForLabel"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/profileImageSpacingForLabel"
        android:padding="@dimen/profileImagePadding"
        android:background="#00ffff"/>  <!-- Added this background for visual debugging -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/profileDefaultText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="#ffff00" /> <!-- Added this background for visual debugging -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add this to your dimens file **dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="custom_profile_image">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="profileImagePadding">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="profileImageSpacingForLabel">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="profileImageLayoutSize">60dp</dimen>
```

Add this to your strings file **strings.xml**

```
<string name="profileDefaultText">0</string>
```

Add this to your colors file **colors.xml**

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```