# Change location of spinner navigation on action bar

Tags: android, navigationbar

I have application with action bar. I tryed to set a real ActionBar, but now it's deprecated. So I found this way. But I want to move navigation spinner to the left side of action bar. If is possible? 
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        String colors[] = {"MyList","Red","Blue","White","Yellow","Black", "Green","Purple","Orange","Grey"};
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_action_bar_spinner_menu, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,colors);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String msg="";
        switch(item.getItemId()){//selected menu item
            case R.id.first:
               //// Logout();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is how spinner menu looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="ActionBar Spinner"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:background="#ff00"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        android:checkable="false" />
</menu>
```

Comment: use [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) and add your own design(views) in it.

Comment: But how I can set spinner on Toolbar?

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27859966/4574463

Comment: part of things mentioned here is deprecated too. I didn't want to set something that already depricated.

Comment: search for custom Toolbar tutorials and adding view in it. (custom toolbar)

Comment: check this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar